# Python "requirement already satisfied" but ModuleNotFoundError:

Tags: modulenotfounderror

I tried to run some code and have error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'happybase'"
But when I run "pip3 install happybase" I've got the message  "Requirement already satisfied"

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'happybase'
PS C:\Users\Mykola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311> pip3 install happybase
Requirement already satisfied: happybase in c:\users\mykola\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\mykola\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from      happybase) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: thriftpy2>=0.4 in c:\users\mykola\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from happybase) (0.4.16)
Requirement already satisfied: ply<4.0,>=3.4 in c:\users\mykola\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from  thriftpy2>=0.4->happybase) (3.11)
PS C:\Users\Mykola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311> 

In my VC I have such interpreters
Python 3.9.13 \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe 
Python 3.11.2 \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe Global
Python 3.9.13 \Anaconda3\python.exe   `                            Conda
```

And looks if I choose 3.9.13 it works! but how to install this package to 3.11.2 Version?
Thanks in advance

I have tried to run pip install happybase from C:\Users\Mykola\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311>
but it didn't help

Comment: try to use the right interpreter to install the module: "Python 3.11.2 \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"  -m pip install happybase